# Express.js - Use nested request to get JSON from backup URL

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, npm-request

I have two URLs that have a `.json.gz` file -

```
var url = "http://post.s3post.cf/s3posts.json.gz";
var backupURL = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s3post.cf/s3posts.json.gz";
```

I'm able to successfully use the *request module* to get `json` from the file -

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    request({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: url,
        gzip: true
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        res.locals.posts = JSON.parse(body);
        next();
    });
});
```

What I want to do is, if the request with `url` fails, I want to use the `backupURL` to get the `json` from. So logically, I thought if I received an error, I would use a nested request to do this -

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    request({
        method: 'GET',
        uri: url,
        gzip: true
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if(error) {
            request({
                method: 'GET',
                uri: backupURL,
                gzip: true
            }, function(error, response, body) {
                res.locals.posts = JSON.parse(body);
                next();
            });
        } else {
            res.locals.posts = JSON.parse(body);
            next();
        }
    });
});
```

This is not working. Individually, both the URLs work with one request. What can I do to use `backupURL` when the request with `url` fails?

**EDIT 1 -**

The program compiles and starts listening to my app. It is when I request a page that it crashes with this error -

```
undefined:1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Request._callback (/Users/Anish/Workspace/NodeJS/unzipper/app.js:65:28)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/Anish/Workspace/NodeJS/unzipper/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/Anish/Workspace/NodeJS/unzipper/node_modules/request/request.js:1171:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/Anish/Workspace/NodeJS/unzipper/node_modules/request/request.js:1091:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
```

Comment: 'Not working' is not a problem description. There are consequences, detail those. Namely any error that is shown. You can also employ some poor-mans-debugging and add console.log statements to see exactly which path the code takes and what the content of variables is at that point.

Comment: @Gimby I have edited my question with the error information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use response.status 
 if its is 200 then move further 
 else if its 400 or 500 then use backup URL

Comment: with `200` status, you can also get `HTML` which produces error while parsing

Comment: @Vipul This worked. I had to just change `if(error)` to `if(error || response.status != 200)`.

Answer (score 1):

> It's parsing error.

`<` it seems like you are getting `HTML` data and at first position you are getting parsing error

Always check your body before parse

```
if(typeof body==='string'){
   body = JSON.parse(body);
}
res.locals.posts = body;
```